# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException:Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting following error when creating a table using following dialect

" org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"

> Hibernate: create table user (id integer not null, name varchar(100), primary key (id)) type=InnoDB
>
> org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:313)
>       at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
>       at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
>       at com.adeptia.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:13)
>       at com.adeptia.hibernate.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:8)
>       at com.adeptia.MainClass.returnHello(MainClass.java:16)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:143)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:160)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:203)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:97)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:303)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:286)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1072)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:399)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>       at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=InnoDB' at line 1
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:112)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:116)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:958)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:808)
>       at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
>       ... 56 more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using MySQL version greater than 5.0 use any one of the following dialect:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

Comment: Add dialect in hibernate context xml file.